# How were the Space Shuttle missions named?

Tags: nasa, space-shuttle, terminology, crewed-spaceflight

For example, why was the 19th Shuttle mission named STS-51F instead of something more obvious like STS-19?

Side note: One reason I'm asking is because in the DVD commentary of [Apollo 13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_13_(film)), Tom Hanks or someone like that mentioned that after that mission, *"you won't find the number 13 anywhere in official NASA titles or launch date/times"* (my rough paraphrasing). Not quite sure if this is true, although it seems to be for Space Shuttle missions at least.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of inadequate research. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Space_Shuttle_missions#Flight_numbering

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wikipedia has [a good summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Space_Shuttle_missions) of this.

STS-1 to STS-9 were numbered sequentially by order of launch, then it switched to a number based on fiscal year (5 for FY 1985), launch site code (1 for KSC, 2 for Vandenberg), and letter. The letters were assigned sequentially at the time of planning, but schedule slips etc meant that they were not launched in this order.

After *Challenger* they dropped this system, and returned to a numeric STS-xx name. As with the letter codes, these were assigned sequentially but got out of sequence as time went on and schedules were moved around - the first flights were 26, 27, 29, 30, 28...

(The STS-xx numeric codes were still used internally during the "letter sequence", referring to the specific payload/mission rather than the launch, but these wouldn't usually be public. This meant that there were some duplicates on internal paperwork, eg two STS-26s, and so the new ones were sometimes listed as STS-26R.)

Comment: Excellent answer.  Mostly it was KSC processing who kept the number codes; JSC switched to the weird fiscal codes.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Ah, the many idiosyncrasies of splitting up the bureaucracy for the sake of more state votes. Oh what a tangled web is woven for us!